# Custom PrintService in ArcGIS WebApp Builder throws error Export Map Tool

Tags: printing, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have WebApp application I am creating with the Developer Edition.
In ArcMap I created a custom print service like described here (https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/create-web-apps/windows/tutorial-publishing-additional-services-for-printing.htm).
When I use the custom PrintService in the Print Widget, no file is exported but an error is thrown: *Error executing tool. Export Web Map.*

When I copy the Web_Map_as_JSON code that is generated, remove the basemap layer (https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer), I can get the PrintService to work when I start from REST endpoint (execute) in the ArcGIS Server Manager.

However, the combination of MapServices (hosted on an internal server) and the ESRI basemap does not seem to work.

When I use the standard PrintService of WAB, I can get an export when I deselect all layers and only print the basemap, but when I add layers of my MapServices, it fails.

Any idea what has to be done to make the print widget working with a custom PrintService?

Comment: Is your print service set to asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Is the printer throwing an error after 60 seconds? If so  try to zoom in to a small area and try to print. If that works it means your server is not exporting the image in 60 seconds which is the maximum time a client can wait.
I am assuming you followed the Esri Tutorial and your printer service is Synchronous.